# what's the equation of these functions , could not find the equation from the picture

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Sometimes I encounter with a situation when I need to know the equation of the function from the pictures, what should I do?

[image]

Comment: What are the situations specifically, multiple choice problems? There is no recovering equations from pictures without a lot of additional information, a host of different equations can have similar looking graphs. The linked ones could correspond to cubic polynomials, for example, $x^3$ and $x(x-1)(x+1)$.

Comment: you could note symmetries .... in both graphs, seems that $f(-x)=-f(x)$

Comment: @Conifold Please post that as an answer. (I think the first curve is meant to be $x^3$ but it's drawn badly. The slope at the origin should be  $0$.)

Comment: @EthanBolker Done.

Answer (score 1):

Typical situations of matching curves to equations occur in multiple choice problems. In general, there is no recovering equations from pictures without a lot of additional information, a host of different equations can have similar looking graphs. If we know that the curves are low degree polynomials we can roughly guess the equations by looking at the roots and behavior at infinity. The OP ones could correspond to cubic polynomials, for example, $x^3$ (single degenerate root, positive at infinity) and $x(x−1)(x+1)$ (three simple roots, positive at infinity).